# Getter within loop returning null after assigning values

Tags: java, oop, loops, null

I've got a slight problem with my program. Simply put, what I do is this:

1. Choose the option to "Add a new Student record".
2. When I try to display the newly added values (First Name, Last Name, Course), it all comes back as null.

I can't wrap my head around what's wrong, but I'll try to post the needed codes in order for all of you to get a better view.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    String cont1=" ";
    String X;        
    int x1,arr_count=1;
    String[] option = {"First Name","Last Name","Course"};

    BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do{      

    System.out.println("\nWelcome! Please select a task: \nA. View a record.\nB. Add a record.\nC. Edit a record.\nD. Exit the program.");
    String option1 = reader1.readLine();

    if("a".equals(option1)|| "A".equals(option1)){
        System.out.println("Please enter the Student ID for the record to view.");
        String a = reader1.readLine();
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        System.out.print(Records.getRecord(x1,y) + " ");
        }            
        System.out.print("\nSubjects and Grades: \n");
        for(int y=3;y<6;y++){
        System.out.print(Records.getRecord(x1,y) + " (" + Records.getRecord(x1,y+3) + ")\n");
        } 

        System.out.println("\nReturn to Main Menu? (Y/N)");
        cont1= reader1.readLine(); 
    }

    else if("b".equals(option1)||"B".equals(option1)){
        arr_count++;
        for (int y = 0; y<3;y++){
        System.out.println("Enter Value for "+ option [y]+":"  ); 
        X = reader1.readLine();
        X = Records.getRecord(arr_count,y);          
        }

        System.out.println("\nNew Student added:\nID number: "+ arr_count);
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        X = Records.getRecord(arr_count,y);
        System.out.print(X + " ");
        }
```

Records class:

```
public class Records {

    public static String getRecord(int recordID,int index1)throws Exception{
        //BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String records[][] = new String [10][9];
        records[0][0] = "John";    records[0][3] = "English";  records[0][6] = "C";
        records[0][1] = "Smith";   records[0][4] = "Math";     records[0][7] = "B";
        records[0][2] = "BS IT";   records[0][5] = "Graphics"; records[0][8] = "A";

        records[1][0] = "Juan";    records[1][3] = "Graphics"; records[1][6] = "B";
        records[1][1] = "Ponce";   records[1][4] = "Math";     records[1][7] = "B";
        records[1][2] = "BS ECE";  records[1][5] = "Robotics"; records[1][8] = "A";

        /**records[2][0] = "";     records[2][3] = "";     records[2][6] = "";
        records[2][1] = "";     records[2][4] = "";     records[2][7] = "";
        records[2][2] = "";     records[2][5] = "";     records[2][8] = "";

        records[3][0] = "";     records[3][3] = "";     records[3][6] = "";
        records[3][1] = "";     records[3][4] = "";     records[3][7] = "";
        records[3][2] = "";    records[3][5] = "";     records[3][8] = "";

        records[4][0] = "";     records[4][3] = "";     records[4][6] = "";
        records[4][1] = "";     records[4][4] = "";     records[4][7] = "";
        records[4][2] = "";    records[4][5] = "";     records[4][8] = "";*/



    return records[recordID][index1];
    }
}
```

I've tried to set blank values to the records array, also putting the function which assigns the new values to the array into the Records class but I still can't find a way to make this work.

Comment: In `Records` you may add a custom exception and custom when the parameters are out of bounds, instead of the predefined compiler validation code, and detect a potential error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the value of the record.

```
X = reader1.readLine();
X = Records.getRecord(arr_count,y);
```

Is discarding the value read.  Create a setValue method in your Record class -

```
X = reader1.readLine();
Records.setValue(arr_count, y, X);
```

--- inRecord
    setValue ( x, y, val ) {
        records[x][y] = val;
    }

Comment: I see your point. I'll give this a try and get back to you with the results. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Main class is not complete. What is the condition for the do while loop to stop? Is there anything else in the main method than this loop?

Comment: I did not show the rest of the code since they're not related to the problem. The do-while is just a "Continue? (Y/N)" option to return to the start.
Thanks for the reply btw. Any little bit helps